# Capture Stripe Payment Intent

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to capture a payment intent I have previously created. The payment intent has been set up and confirmed and I am now looking to complete the payment intent with the final amount and transfer the money to a stripe connect user.

```
  const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.capture({
    id: paymentIntentId,
    amount_to_capture: finalAmount,
    transfer_data:{destination: connectedAccountId,},
  });
```

The above code snippet is what I have so far, I know this is the correct method but I'm getting the following error:

Error: Stripe: Argument "intent" must be a string, but got: [object Object]

It must be to do with how I'm assigning the connect account id. reading the stripe api docs I need to pass the connect account id to the destination field of transfer data.

How should I be passing that in to the nested destination field. My syntax must be wrong.

Here is the stripe documentation for capturing a payment:

[Stripe Capture Payment API Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Are you sure `paymentIntentId` is in fact an id as a string? From the error, it sounds like this might be a payment intent *object* and you'd need to use something like `paymentIntent.id` instead. (`paymentIntentId.id` as a quick correction, but you should rename the variable to represent its contents).</s>

Double check the value of `paymentIntentId` -- it's probably different than you expect.

**Update**: This is due to a misreading of the syntax. The payment intent id is the first argument as a string, with the options in an object as a second argument. So then this is what you need:

```
const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.capture(
  paymentIntentId,
  {
    amount_to_capture: finalAmount,
    transfer_data: { destination: connectedAccountId, },
  }
);
```

Comment: This hasn't helped, the variable is correct that is being used I'm passing that variable into a function its a string and it contains the correct paymentIntentId

Comment: Oh, oops. I misread your snippet. The syntax is a little off here. Let me update.

Comment: Fixed! That should get you squared now :)